# Не удается подключить PDCurses Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Скачала исходники библиотеки, сбилдила mingw компилятором. Теперь мне нужно подключить библиотеку в проект. Скопировала файл pdcurses.h, panel.h & pdcurses.a в директорию проекта, выставила настройки VS. VS находит библиотеку. При запуске "hello world" примера билд падает с ошибками, которые на скрине[image: на скрине]

В чем была моя ошибка?

Comment: Как вы поняли, что MSVC находит библиотеку? Может вы подключили header файлы только.

Comment: При подключении библиотеки подсказывает curses.h

Comment: Когда intellisense подсказывает, это значит, что header'ы нашлись, но это ничего не говорит о подключении самой библиотеки. В свойствах проекта: linker->additional library directories и linker-> additional dependencies посмотрите.

Comment: Библиотеки, собранные MinGW, часто могут не работать в VS, и наоборот.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! У меня неправильно  собиралась библиотека. Решением проблемы было использование уже готовой сборки библиотеки, которую нашла в интернете.